# DD-WRT QoS traffic shaping sharing percentage of overall bandwidth

Tags: router, dd-wrt, bandwidth, tomato

I'm using DD-WRT build 21402 on an Asus RT-N66U and I'd like to use QoS or some kind of traffic/bandwidth shaping to stop any one IP from using up more than 75% of the available bandwidth.

I would also like to be able to view per IP/user bandwidth usage. I found a script to allow me to do this but after installing it I'm still unable to see the bandwidth usage.

If this isn't possible/simple with DD-WRT is it possible with Tomato?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got a N66U, hardware revision B1, myself and flashed Tomato Shibby on it right away. I'm new to Tomato, but in the menus I have seen what I believe are the settings to accomplish what you're looking for: restrict any one UP from using up more than 75% of available bandwidth, and view per IP/user bandwidth. There are also advanced QoS settings and lots of other neat things to experiment with.

I don't have experience with DD-WRT so I can't comment on that.

If you're looking to install Tomato, there are plenty of guides around there, some of them seem overly complicated to me, so I'll try and save you some time. The usual disclaimer applies: I won't take responsibility for anything that occurs as a result of you following my instructions, so follow at your own risk.

1. Download Tomato Shibby firmware, use AIO, from here: http://tomato.groov.pl/download/K26RT-N/build5x-116-EN/Asus%20RT-N66u%2064k/
2. Download Firmware Restoration Tool from ASUS website here: http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=RT-N66U+(VER.B1)&p=11&s=2
3. Manually set your computer's IP address to 192.168.1.10. Use default subnet values. Set gateway to 192.168.1.1
4. Power off router and disconnect everything except for the power and an ethernet cord to your computer
5. Power on your router while holding the WPS button. Power light should blink very quickly. This means you've cleared your NVRAM. Now, power off your router again.
6. Unzip, run installer, and then run the ASUS Firmware Restoration utility. For the file to upload, navigate to the Tomato Shibby firmware you downloaded earlier. Select upload and quickly move to the next step.
7. Power on your router while holding the reset button for about 5-10 seconds. Power light should blink very slowly (on for several seconds, off for several seconds). The light for your computer's ethernet connection should blink, but other lights should be off. You are in recovery mode now.
8. The firmware should upload without issue. It should say that it is restoring the firmware. Be patient, it may take a while. If it says it's failed, don't worry, leave it be! It's actually still going. Be patient, wait another 5-10 minutes. The router will likely reboot a couple times. The router is good to go when you see all the lights on.
9. Clear NVRAM again by powering the router on while holding the WPS button. I didn't do this and I had issues setting the WiFi shared key. Clearning the NVRAM fixed this (this can also be done from within Tomato, under the Administration menu).

Hope that helps,
Eric

Comment: super helpful post, looking to do this too, thx for the step by step :)